# Can a wave vanish at two times?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Suppose $u$ is a solution of

$$
\begin{cases}u_{tt} = \Delta u & \textrm{ in } \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^n, \\
u(0,\cdot) = 0, \\u_t(0,\cdot) = g(x), \end{cases}
$$

with $g$ compactly supported. Immediately, we may note that $u$ is odd in time with respect to $t = 0$ (i.e $u(t,x) = -u(-t,x)$ for all $t,x$).

My question is this:

> can there be an open set $E \subset \mathbb R^n$ and time $t_1 \neq 0$ so that $u(t_1,\cdot)$ vanishes on $E$, but $u_t(t_1,\cdot)$ does not?

In some cases, the answer is clear.

- **$E$ cannot be all of $\mathbb R^n$**; if that were the case, then $u$ would be odd in time (for all $x$) with respect to $t = t_1$ as well, and thus $u$ is actually *periodic* in time for all $x$ ([see answers to my question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601721/what-can-be-said-about-a-function-that-is-odd-or-even-with-respect-to-two-dist)). This will violate local energy decay (for most reasonable wave speeds, including the constant one above, energy of a wave in a bounded set must decrease as $t \to \infty$).

In general, if $u(t_1,\cdot) \equiv 0$ in $E$, we can only conclude that it is odd w.r.t. $t$ in the light cone determined by $E$. In some cases, this is enough to leverage "oddness" again; for example,

- **If $E$ is "on the edge" of the natural support of $u$**: suppose $n = 1$ and $g$ is supported in $(-1,1)$, and $t_1 = 1$. We know by finite speed of propagation, $u(t_1,\cdot)$ and $u_t(t_1,\cdot)$ vanish outside $(-2,2)$. If we suppose $u(t_1,\cdot)$ vanishes on $(1,2)$ (without assuming anything about whether or not the derivative vanishes), then $u$ will be odd with respect to $t_1$ in the light cone determined by $(1,\infty)$. In particular, at a point like $x = 2.1$, where we already knew that $u(t,2.1)$ vanishes for $t \in (-1.1,t_1)$, we can reflect, and conclude $u(t,2.1) = 0$ for $t \in (t_1,t_1 + 1.1)$ as well. Thus, $u$ (and its normal derivative) will vanish on $-1.1 \leq t \leq 2.1$, and we can then use unique continuation (Holmgren's theorem) to determine that $u(t_1,\cdot)$ *and its time derivative* vanish on $(1,2)$.

What about in general though? Is it possible for it to vanish on some other set $E$ which is nestled further inside the natural support of the wave? Also, what is true if you replace "open" by "positive measure"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can happen. In one space dimension, let 
$$g(x) =   (\sin x) \chi_{[-2\pi,2\pi]}  $$ 
The solution of $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$ with $u(x,0)=0$, $u_t(x,0)=g(x)$ is 
$$
u(x,t) =  \frac12\Big ( \cos  \max(x-t,2\pi) - \cos  \min(x+t,2\pi)  \Big) 
$$
In particular, $u(x,\pi)=0$ for $|x|<\pi$. Also, 
$$
u_t(x,t) =  \frac12\Big( \sin  \max(x-t,2\pi) + \sin  \min(x+t,2\pi)  \Big) 
$$
satisfies $u_t(x,\pi)= -\sin x$ for $|x|<\pi$.

The function $g$ can be smoothed out near $\pm 2\pi$ to create a $C^\infty$ example.

To create an example in higher dimensions, let $g$ depend on one coordinate as above, and multiply it by smooth cutoff function that is $\equiv 1$ in a suitably large neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: Ok, great, this answers the question very well. In the days since I've asked this question, I've come to realize that I probably need to add the hypothesis "$g(x) \geq 0$", and your counterexample is a good demonstration of the necessity of this condition. (see this other question of mine: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612081/spherical-means-kirchoffs-formula-for-variable-speed-wave-equation )