# What is the difference between these two wave equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, geometric-interpretation

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612081/spherical-means-kirchoffs-formula-for-variable-speed-wave-equation), there are (at least) two different wave equations with variable wave speed.

Either $c^2(x)$ is outside the Laplacian:
$$
\begin{cases}u_{tt} - c^2(x) \Delta u = 0 \quad \textrm{ in } \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^n \\
u(0,x) = f(x); \quad u_t(0,x)= g(x). \end{cases}
$$
or $c^2(x)$ is between the two nablas:
$$
\begin{cases}u_{tt} - \nabla\cdot(c^2(x)\nabla u) = 0 \quad \textrm{ in } \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^n \\
u(0,x) = f(x); \quad u_t(0,x)= g(x). \end{cases}
$$
My question is, what do the differences in the location of $c^2(x)$ actually represent? What is the physical meaning distinguishing these two equations?

Comment: Consider the second equation (called "divergence form"). If for each $t$, $x\mapsto u(t,x)\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$, then $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\int_{\mathbb R^n}u(t,x)dx=0$, so that $\int_{\mathbb R^n}udx=\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x)+t\int_{\mathbb R^n} g(x)$.  So conservation of the center-of-mass holds in the divergence case.  Note that energy conservation holds in both cases, but the definition of energy is $\int u_t^2+c^2(x)|\nabla u|^2dx$ in the second case.

Comment: I don't understand how you deduce conservation of center-of-mass. Also, the definition of energy only has one time derivative in the divergence form equation?

Comment: If you integrate $u_{tt}-\nabla\cdot(c^2\nabla u)$ over each $B_k(0)$, apply the divergence theorem, and let $k\to\infty$, then $\int_{\mathbb R^n} u_{tt}=\lim\int_{\partial B_k}c^2(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}d\sigma(x)=0$ since $x\mapsto u(t,x)\in C^\infty_c$.

In divergence form, the energy density is $u_t^2+c^2|\nabla u|^2$, but it's $c^{-2}u_t^2+|\nabla u|^2$ in the nondivergence case (your first equation).